# Responsive <ul> list element and clickable <li> with last <li> lot floating left

Tags: html, css, list, css-float

I am having an issue formatting  and

elements to align left. Below is the jsfiddle link. After the elements fill the  and overflow to the next row,

elements inside don't align to the left side.

I've tried placing the  tag inside

elements, however that doesn't allow the entire

tag to be clickable. The goal was for the entire

tag with padding to be clickable.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w381kanu/

Image: [image] (what I am trying to achieve)

Code:

```css
.nobottommargin {
    align-content: left;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}

.clients-grid, .testimonials-grid {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    padding-inline-start: 40px;
}

.clients-grid li, .testimonials-grid li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    padding-top: 16px;
    /* padding-bottom: 24px; */
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}


.clients-grid li a, .clients-grid li img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}

p{
  text-align:center;
}

.clients-grid.grid-6 li {
    width: 12.5%;
}

.li-hover {
  background-color: #F0F8FF;
}

.li-hover:hover {
  background-color: #696969;
}
```

```html
<section id="content">
  <ul class="clients-grid grid-6 nobottommargin clearfix">
    <a href="#">
      <li class="li-hover">
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4018" src="https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000" alt="" width="64" height="64">
        <p>Element One</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="li-hover">
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4018" src="https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000" alt="" width="64" height="64">
        <p>Element Two</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="li-hover">
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4018" src="https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000" alt="" width="64" height="64">
        <p>Earth/Horizon Element</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="li-hover">
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4018" src="https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000" alt="" width="64" height="64">
        <p>One/Two/Three Elements For Elements</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="li-hover">
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4018" src="https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000" alt="" width="64" height="64">
        <p>Another Element</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="li-hover">
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4018" src="https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000" alt="" width="64" height="64">
        <p>Yet Another Element</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="li-hover">
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4018" src="https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000" alt="" width="64" height="64">
        <p>Element Y</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="li-hover">
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4018" src="https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000" alt="" width="64" height="64">
        <p>Element Z</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="li-hover">
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4018" src="https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000" alt="" width="64" height="64">
        <p>Receiver Element</p>
      </li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Is this what you are aiming for? https://jsfiddle.net/wutj9pb6/

Comment: you should place the anchor tags <a> inside the <li> elements , not the opposite, the <li> should be the first child in a list

Comment: side  note, your html is invalid `<li>` must be direct children of the `<ul>` [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element)

Answer (score 1):

the different heights of your li are messing with the formatting.  set height on li in css and you're good to go.  A better answer might be doing this with flexbox.

```css
.nobottommargin {
    align-content: left;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}

.clients-grid, .testimonials-grid {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li{
height:250px;
}

ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    padding-inline-start: 40px;
}

.clients-grid li, .testimonials-grid li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    padding-top: 16px;
    /* padding-bottom: 24px; */
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}


.clients-grid li a, .clients-grid li img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}

p{
  text-align:center;
}

.clients-grid.grid-6 li {
    width: 12.5%;
}

.li-hover {
  background-color: #F0F8FF;
}

.li-hover:hover {
  background-color: #696969;
}
```

```html
<section id="content">
  <ul class="clients-grid grid-6 nobottommargin clearfix">
    <a href="#">
      <li class="li-hover">
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4018" src="https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000" alt="" width="64" height="64">
        <p>Element One</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="li-hover">
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4018" src="https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000" alt="" width="64" height="64">
        <p>Element Two</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="li-hover">
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4018" src="https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000" alt="" width="64" height="64">
        <p>Earth/Horizon Element</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="li-hover">
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4018" src="https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000" alt="" width="64" height="64">
        <p>One/Two/Three Elements For Elements</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="li-hover">
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4018" src="https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000" alt="" width="64" height="64">
        <p>Another Element</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="li-hover">
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4018" src="https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000" alt="" width="64" height="64">
        <p>Yet Another Element</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="li-hover">
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4018" src="https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000" alt="" width="64" height="64">
        <p>Element Y</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="li-hover">
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4018" src="https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000" alt="" width="64" height="64">
        <p>Element Z</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="li-hover">
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4018" src="https://dummyimage.com/250/ffffff/000000" alt="" width="64" height="64">
        <p>Receiver Element</p>
      </li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: you should place the anchor tags <a> inside the <li> elements , not the opposite, the <li> should be the first child in a list

Comment: is there a reference for that in the docs?

Comment: Since HTML5 placing <a> outside <li> elements is valid, however it may not be best practice. @DCR Thank you for the quick response! Why do you recommend going with a flexbox-based approach?  Also what about doing this from a card approach?

Currently looking into that and how to integrate that in! Thanks again!

Comment: Not familiar with the card approach so can't comment on that.  Flexbox is just  simple to use and great for positioning elements. does this solution not work for you?